# Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s) in .NET Core Webdeploy

Tags: .net-core, webdeploy

I've created a new .NET Core project and just tries to deploy it to my localhost.

Build message:
Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."

Where to go?

Comment: how are you deploying it?

Comment: WebDeploy to localhost